# Android: Execute javascript to Jsoup

Tags: java, javascript, android, jsoup

In my website I have a "SHOW MORE" Button which sends javascript to show more text.
I'm trying to make a app that can fetch text from my site.

I'm currently using jsoup, but it returns `"blalblbla + "show more"`
So how do I get that hidden text that isnt show'd onLoad?

Is there anyway to send javascript code to jsoup? or should I use another library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute javascript code with Jsoup. If you want to execute JS, use [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

But if your javascript code sending some HTTP request to get some data(i.e. show  more results), you can imitate this request and get responce data.

Comment: onclick="replace_id('R5','/interface/call?c=display_translations_right%2CR5%2C803506%2Csv%2Cen%2CALL%2C73%2C0%2C1%2C1');return false">

One example of my Button

Comment: Open you website with FireBug or something similar and watch if click on "SHOW MORE" Button sends any request to the site.

Comment: Yeap, you call `replace_id` function here, but I dont know what this function is doing

Comment: You cant call any JS function with Jsoup. What I am trying to say is if your `replace_id` function sending request to the site for "SHOW MORE", you can achive your aim

Comment: HtmlUnit does not work on android (not easily anyway) so that is not really a solution.